# Probability that series of games until one team wins four games, with bias, lasts exactly five games

Tags: probability

Problem: Two teams A and B play a series of games until one team wins four games. We assume that the games are played independently and that the probability that A wins any game is p. What is the probability that the series lasts exactly five games?

My solution: the event that the series lasts exactly five games is a composition event of A wins 4 games in a series of 5 games and B or B wins 4 games in a series of 5 games.

P(exactly 5 games) 
= 5C4.p^4.(1-p) + 5C4.p.(1-p)^4 
= 5[p^4.(1-p) + p.(1-p)^4]

However, the book solution is: **4**[p^4.(1-p) + p.(1-p)^4]

Is my solution wrong?

Comment: What is if $A$ or $B$ wins the first four games?

Comment: the team that ultimately loses can not win the last game (else the series would have already stopped).

Comment: I think for the series to last 5 games, A or B cannot win consecutive first 4 games.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I must exclude (W,W,W,W,L). Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

The terminating condition is that one team has its fourth win; no more games happen after this.   The favoured event is that this happens on the fifth game.

So you want the event that either:

- The first four games contain three wins by team A, and one by team B, in any order; then then team A wins the last game.
- or that team B wins three games and team A wins one game, in any order, then team B wins the last game.

Hence $\binom{4}{3} p^3(1-p)p + \binom{4}{1}p(1-p)^3(1-p)\\ = 4 p^4(1-p)+4 p(1-p)^4$

Answer (score 0):

Given that the series has to last 5 games no team can win 4 consecutive matches else we have a winner and 5th match will not be played.